# Express mongodb find() return nothing but get 200

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, express

I want to return all data in MongoDB, it returns 200, but I cannot get all the data properly.

I am using Express

I am learning to use MongoDB and doing homework for practice. The task just told me to set up the API for MongoDB, they gave me an HTML with a button to test the API, and the HTML will show the API success or not, I cannot check on the HTML.

The task that I fail is told me to get all data from MongoDB.

Here is the task which I fail

> GET  `/api/products` .
> Returns all products in the database as  `{ products: Product[] }`

I success to post data to MongoDB, when I use 'app.get()' to get all my data from MongoDB it fail, but I got 200 for the return, and I can see some data in the log.

That is the `app.get()` that I write

```
app.get('/api/products', (req, res, next) => {
    Product.find().then(
      (product) => {
        res.status(200).json({product});
      }
    ).catch(
      (error) => {
        res.status(404).json({
          error: error
        });
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: If this endpoint returns an empty array with a 200 code that means your db is empty. Are you sure that you have some data on collection ?

Comment: @ZahidÇakıcı I can see some data in the log from reply

Comment: Can you post the frontend code which makes the call to the `get` method?

Comment: @lpizzinidev they gave me this github link for front end
https://github.com/OpenClassrooms-Student-Center/fullstack-activity

Answer (score 0):

The below code seems to work fine for me. Please check it out.

```js
app.get('/api/products', (req, res, next) => {
    Product.find({})
    .exec()
    .then(
      (product) => {
        res.status(200).json({product});
      }
    ).catch(
      (error) => {
        res.status(404).json({
          error: error
        });
      }
    );
  });
```

Comment: still say cannot get anything